# Should i implement lock statement for each function in server client base to avoid multiple requesting?

Tags: multithreading, locking

consider a multiplayer game that every client can request for some action in server.so that client can send a request continuously.
should i have to implement lock statement on each method that client can call to avoid multiple accessing thread(client)?

something like this one?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

is there any better solution?

my game server is photon engine.

if i place this code in a loop with 200 iterate without lock statement,it will show me some ("its not 11") result from multiple threads.

```
public static number n1 = new number();
public static void PlusAndMinusInt()
{
    lock (n1)
    { 
        n1.x++;
        Console.WriteLine($"{n1.x}");
        if (n1.x != 11)
            Console.WriteLine($"its not 11");
         n1.x--;
         Console.WriteLine($"{n1.x}");
     }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the requirements. If you want exclusive access to that object, then synchronization is needed. If you just want a counter that is updated atomically, `AtomicLong` might be all you need.

Comment: @IronMan consider a deposit statement.we shouldn't allow client to create two of 100$ request from server where he has only 100$ on his wallet.right?

Comment: If you can never have a negative balance, then yes you'd want to decrement it exclusively using some form of synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

well i think i got that.

There is no 'at the same time'

When they are called from the same unity client they will have an order and will be executed in that order, if they happen from different clients they will be processed in parallel potentially as they are on different fibers etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Photon, but I think the multithreading synchronizing problem I encountered may be similar.

I once used a Socket library, where each socket can set event triggers upon receiving messages, and it uses multithreads to handle the them;

The solution working for me is to use the `ConcurrentQueue` ; we do not really handle the message immediately.
Rather, the messages are pushed in this queue, and are later de-queued/handled in the Main Thread.

This saved me the hassle of using lock everywhere; hope that is what you want.

Comment: nice.concurrentQueue is the word that i was looking for.but i think i have to extend this concurrentQueue.because consider this scenario that a client will request 3 action.
action 1
action 2
action 1
i need to every action work in concurrent way.but every action can't be called in multi thread way.the action should be completed when anther request for this action is comming.

Comment: I am going to assume that you mean, when 2 identical requests are sent, they must be completed exactly in the order they were sent. In terms of networking, the order of packets sent may depend on the connection protocol you use, let alone the order they are handled by CPU.

Comment: A way to go is to keep track of an `message_id` (integer) at both client and server that only increases by 1, as each request is sent by your client. The server then still sticks to the `ConcurrentQueue`, but when it dequeues a message, it checks that id to be exactly 1, more than the last message processed, or the server should re-queue the message back in the queue, waiting for the message *before it* to come.

Comment: please see this link,my main question has been changed to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508146/how-to-run-3-methods-one-after-another-in-c-sharp-using-threading @Tigerpaws